# Destructuring change name and set default value

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

How can I destructure the nested `routes` and `index` and set a default value?

```
const {
    nav: { index: navIndex = '', routes: navRoutes = '' }
    routes = '', index = ''
} = _navigator.state;
```

I'd like to rename the nested values to `navIndex` and `navRoutes`, any ideas?

Comment: do you have some examples?

Comment: You are missing a comma at the end of the first line ... Otherwise that'll work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take a default object for not given `nav` object

```
const {
        nav: { index: navIndex = '', routes: navRoutes = '' } = {}, 
        routes = '', 
        index = ''
    } = _navigator.state;
```